# Porcentaje que corresponde de varios nombres

Tags: java, eclipse, calculo, porcentaje

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo a programar y me han puesto un ejercicio en el cual debo ir introduciendo caracteres uno a uno de diferentes tipos para que luego el programa me desglose de qué tipo son (por ejemplo, 'x' son vocales, 'y' consonantes, 'z' caracteres especiales).
Hasta ahí todo correcto. Luego, después de varias cosas, me pide que a qué porcentaje corresponde cada uno de ellos.
Bien, yo he usado:

```
double VOC = Math.rint(((voc*100.0)/TOT)*100.0)/100.0;
double CONS = Math.rint(((cons*100.0)/TOT)*100.0)/100.0;
double ESP = Math.rint((((esp)*100.0)/TOT)*100.0)/100.0;
```

La cuestión está en que estoy redondeando a 2 decimales y supongamos que `TOT = 12` (que es el total introducido), `voc=5`, `cons=5` y `esp=2`.
Entonces, con estos números me daría un resultado de `VOC= 41.67 %`, `CONS= 41.67 %` y `ESP= 16.67 %`.

El problema es que no puedo superar el 100%, y con estos resultados se me iría al 100.01%...

Se que el resultado que debería imprimir en pantalla es de `VOC=41.66 %`, `CONS= 41.67 %` y `ESP=16.66 %` ya que me lo marca la consola del enunciado...
Entiendo que estoy haciendo el porcentaje de cada uno por separado y que esto me había servido en otros ejercicios, pero aquí, con esta función, no estoy teniendo en cuenta que no se puede superar el 100%. Como podría resolver esto?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tu problema es de redondeo, al no ser cifras exactas siempre tendrás un error de redondeo, ya sea por defecto o por exceso. Una forma de resolver el problema sería tomando en cuenta precisamente este error al momento de mostrar los datos. Otra forma es aplicar redondeo sobre la suma de los valores y no sobre cada valor individual. Saludos